# scope.data does not have a foreach method

Tags: javascript

I am passing calling a Rest API in a controller, and passing data to a custom Angular controller. The array passing from controller, to directive, needs to be cleaned up /debugged (I think its also related to scope).

I've tried different variations of my code.

Inside my directive.js :

What works: `console.log (scope.data)` - prints out the expected array data.

What does not work : `scope.data.foreach ()` - never works , says

> scope.data does not have a foreach method

.. indicating something is wrong

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Can you show me your code? I think I can help you.

Comment: I think you can use a generic for instead of foreach.
Actually forEach has some drawbacks like we can't use continue in it.

Answer (score 1):

> What does not work : scope.data.foreach () - never works

It seems like you have misspelled it. The correct syntax is:

```
scope.data.forEach(...)
```